# Taking the gradient of function with linear transformation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, gradient-descent, hessian-matrix

I am relatively new to matrix calculus and I cannot figure out why the following equation holds. I have seen this on multiple answers on this site as a given, but I cannot derive this myself.

It is given that A is a linear transformation on the vector x such that g(x) = f(Ax). Then it follows that,

$$
\nabla g(x) = A^{T}\nabla f(Ax)
$$

I was trying to do this approach:

$$
\nabla g(x) =
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial g(x)}{\partial x_1} \\
\frac{\partial g(x)}{\partial x_2} \\
... \\
\frac{\partial g(x)}{\partial x_i} 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Where I get, 
$$
\frac{\partial g(x)}{\partial x_i} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}f(Ax)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}Ax
$$
But I cannot see how this leads to the first equation.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that $A = (a_{ij})$ is an $m\times n$ matrix and $x = (x_{1},...,x_{n})\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. We may write $Ax^{T} = y^{T}$ where $y = (y_{1},...,y_{m})\in \mathbb{R}^{m}$. Note that, for each $j = 1,...,m$ we have $$y_{j} = \sum_{k=1}^{m}a_{jk}x_{k} \Rightarrow \frac{\partial y_{j}}{\partial x_{i}} = a_{ji}.$$ Now, $f(Ax) = f(y_{1},...,y_{m})$ and therefore $$\frac{\partial g(x)}{\partial x_{i}} = \sum_{j=1}^{m}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_{j}}(y_{1},...,y_{m})\frac{\partial y_{j}}{\partial x_{i}} = \sum_{j=1}^{m}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_{j}}(y_{1},...,y_{m})a_{ji}$$
But the last equality is precise the $i$-th coordinate of $A^{T}\nabla f(Ax)$ where I'm considering $\nabla f(Ax)$ as a column vector, as you did.